# Searching on a list with lists in it and deleting the specific list that we searched

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a list that has lists in it:

```
Contact_list = [["Smith", "John", "780 555 3234", "jsmith@gsacrd.ab.ca"], ["Pitts", "Harry", "780 555 7329", "hpitts@gmail.com"], ["Fields", "Sara", "780 555 8129", "sfields@hotmail.com"], ["Smith", "Jane", "780 555 2819", "jsmith@gmail.com"], ["Unger", "Felix", "302 555 3819", "funger@universal.org"]]
```

And I want to make a search on firstname or last name and edit that specific contact' specific element. I wrote code like that:

```
def EditContact():
    editby = raw_input('| 1 | To Search contact and Edit by FirstName:\n| 2 | To Search contact and Edit by LastName: ')
    if editby == '1':
        FirstName = raw_input('Firstname: ')
        EditByFirstName(FirstName)
    elif editby == '2':
        LastName = raw_input('Lastname: ')
        EditByLastName(LastName)
    else:
        print("\n----------------------\nIncorrect choice.\n----------------------\n")
```

as you can understand Trying to find contact by first name or last name here and send them to the def under here

```
def EditByFirstName(First):
    for x in Contact_list:
        if (x[1] == First)  :
            print '\n----------------------\n',x[1],x[0],'Named Contact Found!!!! \n----------------------\n'
            ChangeInformation(x)
        else:
            print "\nThis Contact Does Not Exist!!\n----------------------\n"
def EditByLastName(Last):
    for x in Contact_list:
        if (x[1] == Last)  :
            print '\n----------------------\n',x[1],x[0],'Named Contact Found!!!! \n----------------------\n'
            ChangeInformation(x)
        else:
            print "\nThis Contact Does Not Exist!!\n----------------------\n"
```

Until here everything is ok. but after here attending new thing in List gives error. So problem is in this block of code but couldn't find out what is causing it:

```
def ChangeInformation(x):
    print "| 1 | To Edit Firstname"
    print "| 2 | To Edit Lastname"
    print "| 3 | To Edit PhoneNumber"
    print '| 4 | To Edit Email'
    Edit_Choice = raw_input("Please make a choice:")
    if Edit_Choice == '1':
        NewFirstName = input("Please Enter New Firstname: ")
        Contact_list[x[1]] = (NewFirstName)
        return Contact_list
    elif Edit_Choice == '2':
        NewLastName = raw_input("Please Enter New Lasttname: ")
        Contact_list[x[0]] = NewLastName
        return Contact_list
    elif Edit_Choice == '3':
        NewNumber = raw_input("Please Enter New Number: ")
        Contact_list[x[2]] = NewNumber
        return Contact_list
    elif Edit_Choice == '4':
        NewEmail = raw_input("Please Enter New Email: ")
        Contact_list[[x[3]]]= NewEmail
        return Contact_list
    else:
        print("\n----------------------\nIncorrect choice.\n----------------------\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `ChangeInformation(x)`, you are passing through `x` a member of `Contact_list` which is a list itself. Now, in `ChangeInformation`, you do the following

```
Contact_list[x[0]] = NewLastName
```

which would give a type error since `x[0]` may result to an object of type other than `int` which is invalid for a list index. You should just change it

```
x[0] = NewLastName
```

since you are already passing the list member and remove the `return` statements.